# IOS Device token sent empty to database

Tags: ios, is-empty, devicetoken

I'm trying to send IOS device token to database to use it in notifications using php and Firebase but keep always getting device token empty!!

**AppDelegate code:**

```
    import UIKit
import SlideMenuControllerSwift
import GoogleMaps
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import UserNotifications
import Localize_Swift

var appDefaults = UserDefaults.standard;
var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
  var notificationtoken:String = "";

 func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken , type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)

        self.notificationtoken = deviceToken.base64EncodedString();

        sendDeveiceToken();
    }

}
```

**Login Code**

```
 import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var loginBtn: UIButton!
 var userlogin:userLogin?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        usernameTextField.delegate = self;
        passwordTextField.delegate = self;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func LoginAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        Shared.HUD.progressHUD(nil, message: nil);
        if (usernameTextField.text != nil && passwordTextField.text != nil) {
            //userLogin(user_name: String , password :String, device: String , Token: String )
            GoldenTajProvider.request(.userLogin(user_name: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!,Token: appDelegate.notificationtoken), completion: { (result) in
                var success = true
                var message = "Unable to fetch from GitHub"
                Shared.HUD.hide(2)
                switch result {
                case let .success(moyaResponse):
                    do {
                        let repos = try moyaResponse.mapObject(userLogin)
                        if (repos.data != nil){
                        self.userlogin = repos;
                        if let user = self.userlogin{
                            userLogin.updateUserObject(user)

                            appDelegate.currentUserId = (user.data?.first?.iD!)!
                            appDelegate.currentUser = user;
                        }

                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(accessToken, forKey: AppUserDefaults.AccessToken.rawValue);
                         UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: AppUserDefaults.isLogedIn.rawValue);
                        appDelegate.presentMain();
                        }else {
                            let json  = try moyaResponse.mapJSON() as! [String:Any]
                            message = json["data"] as! String
                            Shared.Alert("", message: message, confirmTitle: "OK", sender: self);


                        }
                    } catch {
                        success = false
                    }

                case let .failure(error):
                    guard let error = error as? CustomStringConvertible else {
                        break
                    }
                    message = error.description
                    success = false
                }

            })

        }



    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which ios version you are testing or developing but
for iOS 10 you need to do additional setup for retrieve/get device token.
You should follow the Firebase Integration document at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Follow the link that will all you need.

Here i am listing some important things

import UserNotifications framework

```
import UserNotifications //For iOS 10
```

Register for **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**

//Appdelegate method to get device token

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .Prod)
    }

func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
            if (granted){
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        })
    }else{ //If user is not on iOS 10 use the old methods we've been using
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This methods are totally documented at Firebase documentation.

Comment: Even with this when I try to send device token to a webservice it go empty:var notificationtoken:String = ""; self.notificationtoken = deviceToken.base64EncodedString();

Comment: get device token with let deviceToken:String? = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()

Comment: This also don't work whenever try to call any of appdelegate strings into login code. keep getting it empty!!

Comment: Hope you are not using simulator

Comment: You must allow push notification when ask, or turn it on from setting